# How to convert current date and time to "20181029093320-0400" this format in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I wan't exactly the date format looks like this one "20181029093320-0400".
I tried this code

```
var requestTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmsszzzz");
```

but I got output like this format "20181029201720+05:30".
Please anyone give me a suggestion to convert date to "20181029093320-0400" this format.

Comment: Is the `-0400` constant or is it supposed to represent a time zone that might change with DST? Changing the offset to a constant -4 hours is easy (`DateTimeOffset.Now.ToOffset(TimeSpan.FromHours(-4))`), but not necessarily what's wanted.

Comment: All of the [custom datetime format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for timezone include a separator. Maybe just post-process the string to remove the `:`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert `-0400` that represents the timezone.If the timezone changed in the sense `(DateTimeOffset.Now.ToOffset(TimeSpan.FromHours(-4)))` is this work??

Comment: It's not clear what you want -- do you want to get `20181029201720+0530` (your local time zone, just with the colon removed)? Then what Damien suggested would work. Do you actually want to change your local time into the offset represented by a different time zone? Then use `TimeZoneInfo`. The latter should not be necessary, because including the offset information is sufficient to tell anyone anywhere in the world what the exact local time is, even if they may have to change it themselves.

Comment: You are getting the correct time. -0400 is New York City Daylight Saving Time.  You are in timezone +5:30.  So you are just seeing a different time due to the timezone differences.